# XS:date returns an error with format YYYYMMDD

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:element name="BeginDate" type="xs:string">
   <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

In the XML I gave

```
     <BeginDate>20100721</BeginDate>
```

but it returns an error ... there is a problem with the code here .. but i am using a validated code :(

So I'm a bit blocked

Comment: The meat of the question has been changed multiple times now since the question was posted. It would really help if what's in the question can at least be trusted to actually be what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the content type twice. You have:
1) attribute `type` on `<xs:element>`
2) `<xs:simpleType>` block as a child of `<xs:element>`.

You can't have both. In this case, you don't need the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that snippet can even be valid, given the `</xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">` thrown in near the end... do I see a copy-paste error there?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the error lies with the regular expression ? Your XML is not valid. What error message do you get ?
Edit: you changed it, but it's still not valid (there is a name attribute in simpleType that should not be used there).